# How to dynamically load values into Tomcat's Context XML file

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

Given that Tomcat's Context XML file tends to contain sensitive information (often including credentials needed to connect to a Database), how can I dynamically load these values from a source other than the plain-text context.xml?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say you have a tomcat/conf/context.xml file that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Resource 
            name="jdbc/MyDB" 
            auth="Container" 
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            removeAbandoned="true" 
            removeAbandonedTimeout="15" 
            maxActive="5" 
            maxIdle="5" 
            maxWait="7000" 
            username="${db.mydb.uid}"
            password="${db.mydb.pwd}"
            driverClassName="${db.mydb.driver}"
            url="${db.mydb.url}${db.mydb.dbName}?autoReconnectForPools=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            factory="com.mycompany.util.configuration.CustomDataSourceFactory"
            validationQuery="SELECT '1';"
            testOnBorrow="true"/>
</Context>
```

What we want to replace in this case is anything in the ${.*} stuff in this resource definition. With slight modification to the code below, however, you can perform these substitutions on pretty much whatever criteria you'd like.

Notice the line `factory="com.mycompany.util.configuration.CustomDataSourceFactory"`

What this means is that Tomcat will attempt to use this factory to process this resource. It should be mentioned that this means that this factory will have to be on Tomcat's classpath on startup (Personally, I put mine in a JAR in the Tomcat `lib` directory).

Here is what my factory looks like:

```
package com.mycompany.util.configuration;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.Name;
import javax.naming.RefAddr;
import javax.naming.Reference;
import javax.naming.StringRefAddr;
import javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory;

public class CustomDataSourceFactory extends BasicDataSourceFactory implements ObjectFactory {

    private static final Pattern _propRefPattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{.*?\\}");

    //http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Adding_Custom_Resource_Factories
    @Override
    public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable environment) throws Exception {
        if (obj instanceof Reference) {
            Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
            System.out.println("Resolving context reference values dynamically");

            for(int i = 0; i < ref.size(); i++) {
                RefAddr addr = ref.get(i);
                String tag = addr.getType();
                String value = (String) addr.getContent();

                Matcher matcher = _propRefPattern.matcher(value);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    String resolvedValue = resolve(value);
                    System.out.println("Resolved " + value + " to " + resolvedValue);
                    ref.remove(i);
                    ref.add(i, new StringRefAddr(tag, resolvedValue));
                }
            }
        }
        // Return the customized instance
        return super.getObjectInstance(obj, name, nameCtx, environment);
    }

    private String resolve(String value) {
        //Given the placeholder, do stuff to figure out what it's true value should be, and return that String.
        //This could be decryption, or maybe using a properties file.
    }
}
```

Then, once this code is on the classpath, restart Tomcat and watch catalina.out for the log messages. NOTE: The `System.out.println` statements will likely end up printing sensitive information to your logs, so you may want to remove them once you are done debugging.

On a sidenote, I wrote this out because I found that many examples were too specific to one specific topic (such as utilizing cryptography), and I wanted to show how this can be done generically. Furthermore, some of the other answers to this question don't explain themselves very well, and I had to do some digging to figure out what needed to be done to make this work. I wanted to share my findings with you guys. Please feel free to comment on this, asking any questions, or making corrections if you find problems, and I'll be sure to roll the fixes into my answer.

Comment: +1 thanks for sharing this. But I still doubt what would be a real world use case where people hardcode details(yes, the sensitive info) inside a code. I mean isn't that the reason why people tend to keep things configurable and maintainable? Besides nobody can hack this info from a context.xml if you look from an enterprise point of view. This file would be handled solely by admin guys.

Comment: when you mention "maybe using a properties file.", how is that diff. from using details directly from context.xml

Comment: This is all true. In reality, we use zookeeper to store and replicate server startup details, because we load balance several servers. In my case, my resolve() uses some other code I wrote to access our Zookeeper stuff on the local box, and we resolve the placeholders to keys within Zookeeper.

Also, Arham, you are right, using a properties file, generally, isn't any different than using the context.xml, except for the fact that you could theoretically store that properties file wherever you wanted.

Comment: This is 2019. I want to use this code to tell my setup to set the jdbc url differently when developing on my system to when it is running in docker containers. This looks like a wonderful starting point.

Answer (score 8):

Why go through all the trouble?

Simply configure the sensitive parameters on the host machine as **JVM system properties** and Tomcat will automatically recognise them and replace the values for all placeholders `${...}`. 
This way the sensitive data stays *on the host machine only* and is never leaked in the source code.

From: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/

> Apache Ant-style variable substitution is supported; a system property with the name propname may be used in a configuration file using the syntax ${propname}. All system properties are available including those set using the -D syntax, those automatically made available by the JVM and those configured in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.

@ Note: This answer assumes that your `context.xml` and other Tomcat config files are under SCM, which is what typically happens when using virtualized deployment (e.g. Openshift).

Comment: +1 This is the best answer and should rightfully be the accepted answer. Tomcat has native support for variable substitution in `context.xml`. The other solutions are hacky workarounds.

Comment: It should be noted that setting any value with -D and passing on the command line will (on UNIX) show these values when listing running processes and any user can see it. That's OK for uninteresting data but for (say) passwords that's a problem.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do this you can implement your own class that implements the very simple

> org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.PropertySource

interface and register this using the system property

> org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE

We did the same for being able to use encrypted values in context.xml, server.xml etc.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Property_replacements

If you are implementing a zookeeper property source I am interested in the result as I am considering to do the same.

Comment: Well, the answer I gave is almost verbatim from code I wrote and use. I implemented resolve to use `com.netflix.curator.framework.*` stuff to yank things out of Zookeeper. It was NOT an easy setup, but it's made configuration management a lot more simple.

Comment: @rswart: do you know where it's possible to find an implementation example org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.PropertySource?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The question implies an infinite regress. If you have a secure source to load the credentials from, you will then need to define credentials for the secure source, and so on +ad infinitum.+

Ultimately the answer to this sort of thing is physical security of the server machine, and access control over who can see its deployment directories from outside.

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear. While technically you are correct, security isn't (in my opinion) black and white. Loading these values from a more obfuscated source is more secure than leaving them out there in the open. Again, if malicious activity is afoot, it doesn't much matter where you load them from. There are ways, I suppose, to circumvent this (say, a hard-coded AES key in obfuscated Java classes...), but in general, you are correct.